# How to show specific Sentry alerts to specific users only?

Tags: error-handling, sentry, alerts, react-native-sentry, product-management

Development team uses Sentry to get technical alerts. Some technical failures need to be communicated to business team also. Business team is also tech savvy and can have sentry accounts. Is there an option in Sentry to send certain technical alerts to specific set of users?

Comment: You can have rules such as that a different threshold goes to one team and another to another team. Add those users to team, etc: https://docs.sentry.io/product/alerts-notifications/